# Using same domain controller for multiple virtual networks in azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-virtual-network

In a azure virtual network(say vnet1) I have 2 virtual machines(say VM1 & VM2).I have windows server active directory installed in VM1. In vnet setting in azure I have mentioned VM1 as my DNS server.So I can use user credentials in AD(from VM1) to login to VM2.Now I want another virtual network(vnet2) to use same AD(in vnet1) so that I could login to the virtual machines in vnet2 using user credentials in AD in vnet1.I tried putting in public IP of VM1 as a DNS setting in vnet2 but that did not work.I would like to know if this is possible? or I have to use another windows server active directory which would be part of my vnet2?

I would also like to know if there are any network limitations on AD?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You net to do a Site to Site between the Vnets.

Depending on if you are using ASM (Azure Service Manager) or ARM (Azure Resource Manager) the solution might have a different setup and there are many blog posts on how to do a Vnet to Vnet connection but i always try to use the official documentation since it always has the latest supported information.

Here is the guide you are looking for.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-configure-vnet-to-vnet-connection/

Comment: Thanks Michael.Will check that out.One more thing I would like to know that is it possible to use a standalone vm(not part of any vnet), with windows server AD installed, for multiple VNETs?

Comment: Hi, you would need a gateway to connect the Vnets and therefore you should put the AD vm in a Vnet and build the "bridges" to the othe Vnets.